# Find polynomials $p_n$ on $[0,1]$ with integral $=3$ and converges pointwisely to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Prove that there  is a sequence of polynomials $\{p_{n}\}$ such that $p_{n} \to 0$ pointwise on $[0,1]$, but such that 
$$\int_{0}^{1}p_{n}(x)dx=3.$$

> **My thought**: 
>   I was thinking of working with a seuqence of functions that has pointwise limits to equal to $0$ but the integral to equal $3$. And then using the Weiestrass approximation theorem to say that there is a $p_n$ that would approximate the functions. I just can't think of the functions that would work.

Comment: What sort of machinery do you have to attack this problem with? Are you aware, for instance, of the space $L^1([0,1])$ and the fact that polynomials are dense in it?

Comment: Maybe this answer might give you some inspiration: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771957/continuous-functions-that-pointwise-converge-to-zero-but-the-integral-tending-t.

Comment: yes I know about L'([0,1]) but how can I use this?

Comment: The question is interesting but it will get closed if you don't provide some details and context, as well as your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $p_n(x) = 3x^n(1-x)(n^2+3n+2)$. Each $\displaystyle\int_0^1p_n  = 3$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following works:

$$p_n(x)=3(n+1)(1-x)^n$$

Observe the above sequence of polynomials do not converge to zero when $\;x=0\;$

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Thank you very much, you're correct. Editing....

Comment: Then it does not converge to $0$ pointwisely

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you. I think it does, since $\;0<x<1\implies x^n\to 0\;$

Comment: It's on $[0,1]$ though. You might need to multiply $(1-x)$ to cut it off at $x=1$.

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you, just did as I didn't see that $\;1\;$ . Anyway, I don't think one point makes a huge difference. Now I need to check the integral.

Comment: I am sorry I should be clear. After that $(1-x)$ you should also do something else so that the integral is still $3$.

Comment: Well, you know: when trying to correct things one should wait a little more than 20 seconds. I think it is correct now.

Comment: Well, that's the same problem now at $x=0$?

Comment: Now it does not converge at $x=0$.

Comment: Yup...let us let the asker sort that out if he wants. I can't right now, and perhaps neither later. I think one point makes no difference yet the question maybe designed to make it more difficult. I can't say.

Comment: so you would try to figure out a polynomial that works by trial an error? I was thinking of working with a function that has pointwise limits to equal to 0 but the integral to equal 3. And then using the Weiestrass approximation theorem to say that there is a pn that would approximate the function. I just can't think of a function that would work

Comment: @math_help_SOS I thought I had it but, as was correctly said above, it wasn't. Both my examples almost work, but one single point in the left or right exteme point of the interval screws it all. If you want something for the half open interval there you have.

Comment: thanks for your help, this did make the question a bit clearer. i'll just try to figure it out from here. Maybe i'll come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the Weiestrass approximation theorem, try to use the following sequence of continuous functions:

$$f_n(x) = \max \{ 0, 3n(1-n|x-2/n|)\}.$$

Note that $f_n$ has a peak at $2/n$, and is zero away from $[1/n, 3/n]$.

I suspect an explicit construction as in the other answer works too.